# Erro na ordem de execução de pthreads

Tags: c, posix

A minha função `main` estava assim (`fnThread` estava definida mais atrás):

```
int main() {

  int i;
  int *result;

  pthread_t tid[N];

  for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    if (pthread_create (&tid[i], 0 ,fnThread, (void*)(&i)) != 0){ 
      printf("Erro ao criar tarefa.\n");
      return 1;
    }
    printf("Lancou uma tarefa\n");
  }


  for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    if (pthread_join (tid[i], (void**)(&result)) != 0) {
      printf("Erro ao esperar por tarefa.\n");
      return 2;
    }
    printf("Tarefa retornou com resultado = %d\n", *result);
  }
return 0;
}
```

Mas, ao correr o código, a ordem das `pthreads` saiu trocada. Na `main` criei um vetor de inteiro `args` e alterei o primeiro `for` para o seguinte:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    args[i] = i;
    if (pthread_create (&tid[i], 0 ,fnThread, (void*)(&args[i])) != 0){ 
        printf("Erro ao criar tarefa.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Lancou uma tarefa\n");
}
```

... e já retornou bem. Alguém me sabe explicar porquê?

Answer (score 1):

Voce está certa: A `ordem de criação` e a `ordem de execução` das threads não é a mesma! E isso não se trata de um erro, e sim do comportamento natural das `pthreads`.

Não é uma boa prática ficar fazendo conversões (`casts`) de valores inteiros para ponteiros e *vice-versa*, isso pode ser o motivador do erro que você mencionou na sua pergunta.

Segue um exemplo (testado) demonstrando como utilizar uma técnica na qual um contexto é criado para cada thread e seu ponteiro repassado da thread principal para as threads filhas (e *vice-versa*) de forma bem flexível e sem conversões perigosas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N  (10)

typedef struct thread_context_s {
    pthread_t tid;
    int id;
    int status;
} thread_context_t;


void * fnThread(void* arg){
    thread_context_t * ctxt = (thread_context_t*) arg;
    printf("Executando tarefa id: %d\n", ctxt->id );
    ctxt->status = ctxt->id;
    return ctxt;
}

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    thread_context_t ctxt[N];

    for( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        ctxt[i].id = i;
        if(pthread_create( &ctxt[i].tid, 0, fnThread, (void*) &ctxt[i] )) {
            printf("Erro ao criar tarefa id: %d\n", i );
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Lancou tarefa id: %d\n", i );
    }

    for( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        if(pthread_join( ctxt[i].tid, NULL )) {
            printf("Erro ao esperar por tarefa id: %d\n", ctxt[i].id );
            return 2;
        }
        printf("Tarefa id: %d retornou: %d\n", ctxt[i].id, ctxt[i].status );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compilando:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pthread thread.c -o threads
```

Testando:

```
./threads 
Lancou tarefa id: 0
Lancou tarefa id: 1
Lancou tarefa id: 2
Lancou tarefa id: 3
Executando tarefa id: 0
Lancou tarefa id: 4
Lancou tarefa id: 5
Executando tarefa id: 2
Lancou tarefa id: 6
Executando tarefa id: 3
Lancou tarefa id: 7
Executando tarefa id: 1
Lancou tarefa id: 8
Executando tarefa id: 4
Executando tarefa id: 7
Lancou tarefa id: 9
Tarefa id: 0 retornou: 0
Tarefa id: 1 retornou: 1
Executando tarefa id: 8
Tarefa id: 2 retornou: 2
Tarefa id: 3 retornou: 3
Executando tarefa id: 9
Executando tarefa id: 6
Tarefa id: 4 retornou: 4
Executando tarefa id: 5
Tarefa id: 5 retornou: 5
Tarefa id: 6 retornou: 6
Tarefa id: 7 retornou: 7
Tarefa id: 8 retornou: 8
Tarefa id: 9 retornou: 9
```